# Spiky hotend and bed temps

Tags: hotend

I recently rebuilt my A8 printer to have a metal frame and replaced the board with a GT2560 reva+. I'm having problems with the temp readings from both my hotend and hotbed. Using marlin 1.1x and Its possible I have something configured incorrectly. I can get successful prints with good quality but sometimes I get thermal runaway during a print.

Both cold and at temp (200c) have fairly large temp spikes. I didn't have this problem with my old board. I had much smoother temp curves. I'm using the default PID values for Ultimaker Kp 22.2, Ki 1.08, Kd 144.

I have tried to use PID autotune but get drastically different values every time I run it and using the results gave worse results (sometimes giving a heating error during the autotune). I checked all the wiring and nothing looks frayed or damaged.

First pic is cold temps. Second is trying to do a PID tune. Third and fourth are during a print.

[image: Temps cold]

[image: PID tune]

[image: During a print]

[image: During a print 2]

Comment: Are you sure the fourth is during a print? Looks like PID auto tune to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and there could be three reasons(if the connections are ok):

- thin wires to the hotend
- one of the MOSFETs was fried
- the termal sensor wasn't good enough insert into the hotend

Try to measure the hotend heating element voltage while printing.

Comment: One of the mosfets on the board was bad. Just replaced the board and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

This really looks like a bad connection, so try with your old board to see if the broken connection is on the board, or it's the temp sensor or the wires.

I had exactly this problem with a bad connection from the temp sensor.

If you didn't break anything, it's the board that's fried / badly connected.